# Setting up Google Wallet merchant account without business

Tags: android

I'm 18 years old and have recently made an app, which I would like to sell on Android market. I already own a developer account, but Google says that I need Google Wallet merchant account to sell my apps. My country is supported, but the registration asks me for my business information, which I obviously do not have.
What can I do to sell my app ? Do I have to own a business ?
Thanks!

Comment: The legal entity is the company or individual the account is registered to. If you don't have a "business", you'll register using your personal name, address, and tax identification.

Comment: Ok I understand now, but what should I then write into "Business Name", when registering ?

Comment: The "business name" is your full name.

Comment: Does the address gets displayed in the android app store? I cannot have my home address somewhere on the play store - it would be really weird if that happens.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Google terms of use and legal identification.

Comment: @rds I see why this question was closed. But obviously it's not clear enough from the Google documentation. If you can refer to a documentation I would be happy. I'm wondering where else you would ask such questions?